# How to get fullscreen in Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox

I am using `VirtualBox`. I have also added an `Operating system` to it. Now i need to know how to get a fullscreen view from it. What i get now is a centered screen and i find it difficult to work with.

I am running WIndows 8 on a Mac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should press `right Ctrl + F` and it will go full screen, or do you mean bigger resolution ? also have you installed Guest additions ? located on Devices menu !

Or, click on 'View' in the left top corner, click on windowed mode, and your virtual screen will fill your physical screen but the resolution will be bad. Next, go into settings in your virtual Ubuntu and adjust the resolution till you are happy with the display. It might also help to set the guest OS display settings to 'None' instead of 'Automatic' as advised on many websites.

Comment: I meant by bigger resolution. I don't know how to install Guest Addition, could you guide me ? Where is the device menu (in Virtual Box or in Windows 8) ?

Comment: Sure, in Virtual Box when you start your virtual machine, there's a menu in the top border of your machine's window, there you can find the 'Devices' menu item, once you open it you'll find 'install guest additions' click it while running your virtual machine !

Comment: I just did. Nothing hapence. I even checked the Download Folder in WIndows 8. But its empty (Nothing was downloaded).

Comment: Take a look [here](http://ludwigkeck.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/virtualbox-guest-additions-in-a-windows-8-virtual-machine/) and let me know !

Comment: Glad to hear, enjoy !